# Remove outline from extjs button

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I know that in order to remove the dotted outline from a link I need to do the following:

```
a, a:active, a:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

However, when using extjs buttons, this does not work.

I have tried setting borders to none and also using outline: none !important. However, none of these things work. Also, I've tried giving it outline none to .x-btn, .x-btn-focus, .x-focus, etc. with no results.

Can anyone help me? I am testing using Ext JS 5.1.1.451 Classic.

EDIT: I am terribly sorry. I don't know how to share the Sencha Fiddle. Here is the test code. This uses Extjs 5.1

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 500,
        items: [{
            // xtype: 'button', // default for Toolbars
            text: 'Button'
        }, {
            xtype: 'splitbutton',
            text: 'Split Button'
        },
        // begin using the right-justified button container
        '->', // same as { xtype: 'tbfill' }
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'field1',
            emptyText: 'enter search term'
        },
        // add a vertical separator bar between toolbar items
        '-', // same as {xtype: 'tbseparator'} to create Ext.toolbar.Separator
        'text 1', // same as {xtype: 'tbtext', text: 'text1'} to create Ext.toolbar.TextItem
        {
            xtype: 'tbspacer'
        }, // same as ' ' to create Ext.toolbar.Spacer
        'text 2', {
            xtype: 'tbspacer',
            width: 50
        }, // add a 50px space
        'text 3']
    });
}
});
```

You can try to click the button and see the link outline.

This is what I am referring to:

[image: Here's the issue]

Also, if it helps, I am using Chrome on Debian.

Comment: in what kind of browsers you run into a problem?

Comment: Please make an example page where we can clearly see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the following CSS:

```
.x-btn-focus.x-btn-default-toolbar-small .x-btn-wrap {
    outline: 1px dotted #333333;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring to the "dotted" outline you see when you click a link. It shows after you click a button. Thanks, though!

Comment: My browser doesn't have that behavior - you'll want to say what browser you use as somebody else asked as well.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. OS is Debian (if that makes a difference). I also edited my original post with the image of what I'm seeing.

Comment: Something else I realized: It only happens with the "classic" version of ExtJs, such as Ext JS 5.1.1.451 Classic